# Java Arraylist of object remove elements from an arraylist by date

Tags: java, arraylist

This is my arraylist

```
ArrayList<Courses> list = new ArrayList<Courses>();
list.add( new Courses(350,5/20/2020) );
list.add( new Courses(350,4/20/2019 );
list.add( new Courses(350,3/20/2018) );
list.add( new Courses(360,6/20/2020) );
list.add( new Courses(360,5/20/2019) );
list.add( new Courses(370,5/20/2020) );
list.add( new Courses(370,5/19/2018) );
list.add( new Courses(360,4/10/2016) );

public class Courses{
 int coursenum;
 Date date;

}
```

How can I remove elements so that the arraylist contains only those elements with the latest date?

Should like this;

```
350, 5/20/2020}
360,6/20/2020}
370, 5/20/2020
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Java 1.7 and java.time through ThreeTen Backport

```
    ArrayList<Course> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add( new Course(350, "5/20/2020") );
    list.add( new Course(350, "4/20/2019") );
    list.add( new Course(350, "3/20/2018") );
    list.add( new Course(360, "6/20/2020") );
    list.add( new Course(360, "5/20/2019") );
    list.add( new Course(370, "5/20/2020") );
    list.add( new Course(370, "5/19/2018") );
    list.add( new Course(360, "4/10/2016") );
    
    // Find latest date for each course number
    Map<Integer, LocalDate> latestDates = new HashMap<>();
    for (Course currentCourse : list) {
        LocalDate latestHitherto = latestDates.get(currentCourse.getCourseNumber());
        if (latestHitherto == null || currentCourse.getDate().isAfter(latestHitherto)) {
            latestDates.put(currentCourse.getCourseNumber(), currentCourse.getDate());
        }
    }
    
    // Remove courses that haven’t got the latest date
    Iterator<Course> courseIterator = list.iterator();
    while (courseIterator.hasNext()) {
        Course currentCourse = courseIterator.next();
        if (currentCourse.getDate().isBefore(latestDates.get(currentCourse.getCourseNumber()))) {
            courseIterator.remove();
        }
    }
    
    // Print result
    for (Course currentCourse : list) {
        System.out.format("%3d %s%n", 
                currentCourse.getCourseNumber(), 
                currentCourse.getDate().format(Course.dateFormatter));
    }
```

Output from this snippet was:

> ```
> 350 5/20/2020
> 360 6/20/2020
> 370 5/20/2020
> ```

I ran on jdk1.7.0_67. I had added ThreeTen Backport 1.3.6. See the link below.

Here is the `Course` class I used:

```
public class Course {
    
    public static final DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/u");
    
    private int courseNumber;
    private LocalDate date;
    
    public Course(int courseNumber, String dateString) {
        this.courseNumber = courseNumber;
        this.date = LocalDate.parse(dateString, dateFormatter);
    }

    public int getCourseNumber() {
        return courseNumber;
    }

    public LocalDate getDate() {
        return date;
    }
}
```

If you insist on using `java.util.Date` — a poorly designed and long outdated class — (1) I would not understand why you would, (2) you can probably modify my code to use `Date` instead.

### Stream version

You may want consider upgrading your Java version. Java 15 is out, and an early access edition of Java 16. Already in Java 8 comes streams. They will allow you to obtain the same in much fewer lines of code:

```
    Collection<Course> filteredCourses = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Course::getCourseNumber,
                    Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Course::getDate)),
                            Optional::orElseThrow)))
            .values();
    List<Course> filteredList = new ArrayList<>(filteredCourses);
    filteredList.forEach(c -> System.out.format(
            "%3d %s%n", c.getCourseNumber(), c.getDate().format(Course.dateFormatter)));
```

> ```
> 370 5/20/2020
> 360 6/20/2020
> 350 5/20/2020
> ```

As the code stands it doesn’t give the same order of courses in the resulting list, and it requires Java 10 (the overlaoded no-arg `orElseThrow` method was introduced there). Even if you require the same order, streams will still be extremely helpful.

### Question: Can that work on Java 1.7?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On older Android either use desugaring or the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. In the latter case make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Comment: Nice answer! For future visitors, it can be improved for two things: (1) A full-fledged Java-8 solution can be added. This can have JSR 310 as well as features like `Collection#removeIf` (if required) etc. (2) A solution based on legacy API can be added. This is important because I can recall about two projects (in my career) in which clients rejected the idea of using 3rd party libraries which were not there in the already approved list.

Comment: Thank you, @Arvind. I could write a much longer stream answer, have just added one example for now. For a way using the terrible classes from Java 1.0 and 1.1, (1) I don’t really consider it helpful to help users use those, (2) I already said that you can fairly easily substitute `Date` into my Java 1.7 code, that will have to suffice. Or you will have to write that solution in your own answer. Thanks for explaining why you often add such a solution in your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Define a key date and remove all courses whose date is before your key date. Provided you have the appropriate getter:

```
ArrayList<Courses> list = new ArrayList<Courses>();
//populate list

Date someDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse("01/01/2020");

list.removeIf(c -> c.getDate().before(someDate));
```

Kindly @Randy Casburn has written a minimal yet complete example which I do not want to withhold from the interested reader:

```
/**
 *
 * @author Randy Casburn
 */
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Date latest = new Date("1/1/2020");
        List<Courses> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Courses(350, new Date("5/20/2020")));
        list.add(new Courses(350, new Date("4/20/2019")));
        list.add(new Courses(350, new Date("3/20/2018")));
        list.add(new Courses(360, new Date("6/20/2020")));
        list.add(new Courses(360, new Date("5/20/2019")));
        list.add(new Courses(370, new Date("5/20/2020")));
        list.add(new Courses(370, new Date("5/19/2018")));
        list.add(new Courses(360, new Date("4/10/2016")));

        list.removeIf(course -> !course.date.after(latest));
        list.forEach(l-> System.out.println(l.date));
    }
}

class Courses {
    int coursenum;
    Date date;
    Courses(int coursenum, Date date){
        this.coursenum = coursenum;
        this.date = date;
    }

}
```

Comment: You beat me to it :-) - here is a repl I put together to show this technique. You are welcome to clone it and include in your answer. https://repl.it/@randycasburn/GlaringSoulfulNet#Main.java

Comment: I should note, that I used Date (although deprecated) because that is what the OP used.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Thank you very much for your example.

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend to use [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) from java-8, since [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) is older version

```
public class Courses{
    int coursenum;
    LocalDate date;

  }
```

And then you can use `removeIf`

```
list.removeIf(d->d.isBefore(LocalDate.now());
```

Answer (score 0):

I am attaching my code as an idea for you request. You can play around with it.

```
public class Courses {

    int courseNum;

    LocalDate date;

    public Courses(int courseNum, LocalDate date) {
        this.courseNum = courseNum;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public int getCourseNum() {
        return courseNum;
    }

    public void setCourseNum(int courseNum) {
        this.courseNum = courseNum;
    }

    public LocalDate getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(LocalDate date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @Override public String toString() {
        return new StringJoiner(", ", Courses.class.getSimpleName() + "[", "]")
                .add("courseNum=" + courseNum)
                .add("date=" + date)
                .toString();
    }

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Courses> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Courses(350, LocalDate.of(2020, 5, 20)));
        list.add(new Courses(350, LocalDate.of(2019, 4, 20)));
        list.add(new Courses(350, LocalDate.of(2018, 3, 20)));
        list.add(new Courses(360, LocalDate.of(2020, 6, 20)));
        list.add(new Courses(360, LocalDate.of(2019, 5, 20)));
        list.add(new Courses(370, LocalDate.of(2020, 5, 20)));
        list.add(new Courses(370, LocalDate.of(2018, 5, 19)));
        list.add(new Courses(360, LocalDate.of(2016, 4, 10)));

        List<Courses> res = list.stream().filter(c -> c.getDate().getYear() == 2020).collect(Collectors.toList());

        res.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it with something other than removeIf?  I am using JDK  1.7.

Comment: @NennaAnya It can be done in Java 1.7, but a lot of things will be a lot easier if you can upgrade to a newer Java version. Java 15 is out, and early access version of Java 16.

Comment: @NennaAnya we are using filter here and not removeIf from Java 8. We can do it without filter. We can iterate over the array and do filter manipulations with it .